# How to export turtle models in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I've created 2 turtle models in an empty NetLOgo project, I wish to use these models in other NetLOgo project but when I open it I don't see the ones I just created in my empty project. I thought model library was a global thing.

Any ideas on how use my custom turtle models in any NL project?

Comment: I am unclear on the question are you talking about the netlogo commons or the models library? I fear my answer may be copy and paste.

Comment: Agree, the question is unclear. What does "I've created 2 turtle models in an empty NetLogo project" mean? It might help if you included your code, and/or a screen shot.

Comment: I haven't written any code... I purely "drawed" 2 turtle models, yeah in the models library. but when I try to open another project I cannot see the ones I just created, you see? They're only available in the project where you drawed them. It's there a way to make them available in any project at any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "empty project" is not part of the Models Library: the library is composed of models that are shipped with NetLogo; custom models cannot be added to it.

That being said, you can still import your turtle shapes in another model. Just save the model in which you've created the shapes somewhere, open the model in which you want to import them, and use the **Import from Model...** button in the Turtle Shapes Editor to import the shapes from your original model:

[image]